# React update array state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am quite new with React and Redux. I manage to update existing item within an array with the following

```
case ACTION_TYPES.SET_PREPARATION_ITEM:
      const { id, x, y, rotation } = action.payload;
      const currentPreparationItem = state.entity.preparationItems[id];
      currentPreparationItem.x = x;
      currentPreparationItem.y = y;
      currentPreparationItem.rotation = rotation;
      return { ...state, preparationItems: { ...state.entity.preparationItems } };
```

Now I am trying to add new item into the array with the following code

```
case ACTION_TYPES.ADD_PREPARATION_ITEM:
      const implant: IProductMySuffix = action.payload;
      const preparationItem: IPreparationItemMySuffix = {};
      preparationItem.x = 10;
      preparationItem.y = 10;
      preparationItem.productId = implant.id;
      preparationItem.image = implant.image;
      preparationItem.imageContentType = implant.imageContentType;
      const result = { ...state, preparationItems: { ...state.entity.preparationItems.concat(preparationItem) } } 
      return result;
```

If I debug correctly, `result` const will have an array with one item. However the in the render method it does not seem to detect if the array has any elements. Any idea what might cause this ?

Added portion of my components

```
const mapStateToProps = (storeState: IRootState) => ({
  users: storeState.userManagement.users,
  customers: storeState.customer.entities,
  businesses: storeState.business.entities,
  products: storeState.product.entities,
  preparationEntity: storeState.preparation.entity,
  loading: storeState.preparation.loading,
  updating: storeState.preparation.updating,
  updateSuccess: storeState.preparation.updateSuccess
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getUsers,
  getCustomers,
  getBusinesses,
  getEntity,
  getProducts,
  updateEntity,
  setBlob,
  createEntity,
  reset,
  setPreparationItem,
  addPreparationItem
};
```

Comment: Can you please post the `mapstatetoprops`, `mapdispatchtoprops` from your Component.

Comment: You haven't mapped `preparationItems` in `mapStateToProps`. Is that correct?

Comment: Why do you have 2 different places where you store `preparationItems`? `state.preparationItems` and `state.entity.preparationItems`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you're mutating the state, which is against redux's rules

```
case ACTION_TYPES.SET_PREPARATION_ITEM:
      const { id, x, y, rotation } = action.payload;
      const currentPreparationItem = {...state.entity.preparationItems[id]}; // create a new object instance
      currentPreparationItem.x = x;
      currentPreparationItem.y = y;
      currentPreparationItem.rotation = rotation;
      const entity = state.entity ? {...state.entity} : {};
      const preparationItems = entity.preparationItems ? [...entity.preparationItems] : [] // Create a new Array instance
      preparationItems[id] = currentPreparationItem;
      entity.preparationItems = preparationItems;
      return {
        ...state,
        entity
      };
```

Second: you're spreading `preparationItems` as an object, but it's actually an array (based on your question description)

```
case ACTION_TYPES.ADD_PREPARATION_ITEM:
      const implant: IProductMySuffix = action.payload;
      const preparationItem: IPreparationItemMySuffix = {};
      preparationItem.x = 10;
      preparationItem.y = 10;
      preparationItem.productId = implant.id;
      preparationItem.image = implant.image;
      preparationItem.imageContentType = implant.imageContentType;
      const entity = state.entity ? {...state.entity} : {};
      // Create a new Array instance and add the new object at the end
      entity.preparationItems = entity.preparationItems ? [
        ...entity.preparationItems,
        preparationItem
      ] : [preparationItem];
      const result = {
        ...state,
        entity
      } 
      return result;
```

Comment: I edited the answer to handle `state.entity.preparationItems` instead of `state.preparationItems`, since you, @abiieez answered via a comment that this is the right place for `preparationItems`

Comment: so far so good, however now I get error during `ADD_PREPARATION_ITEM`. => Cannot access 'preparationItems' before initialization

Comment: I updated the answer to handle the undefined `state.entity`

Comment: Updated again to handle undefined `state.entity.preparationItems` also

Comment: why theres this line `entity.preparationItems = const result = { ...state, entity };`. This gives me syntax error.

Comment: Sorry, I had to remove that line. Code is edited now